# When should parameters be replaced while changing basis?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-information

I have the following equality:
$$a\lvert 00\rangle + b\lvert 11\rangle = a\lvert ++\rangle + b\lvert --\rangle$$
for any $a,b \in C$ that satisfy the normalization condition.

For $a = \frac{1}{\sqrt2}$ and $b = \frac{1}{\sqrt2}$, the equation is satisfied. I wrote:

$$\begin{align}
\lvert +\rangle &= \frac{1}{\sqrt2}\lvert 0\rangle + \frac{1}{\sqrt2}\lvert 1\rangle \\
\lvert -\rangle &= \frac{1}{\sqrt2}\lvert 0\rangle - \frac{1}{\sqrt2}\lvert 1\rangle
\end{align}$$

So: 
$$\begin{align}
a\lvert ++\rangle + b\lvert --\rangle
&= \frac{1}{\sqrt2}\biggl(\frac{1}{\sqrt2}\lvert 0\rangle + \frac{1}{\sqrt2}\lvert 1\rangle\biggr)^2 + \frac{1}{\sqrt2}\biggl(\frac{1}{\sqrt2}\lvert 0\rangle - \frac{1}{\sqrt2}\lvert 1\rangle\biggr)^2 \\
&= \frac{1}{\sqrt2}\lvert 00\rangle + \frac{1}{\sqrt2}\lvert 11\rangle
\end{align}$$

I know that equation isn't generally true but I don't know how to show this with an example (e.g. $a = 1$, $b = 0$). I don't know if I should leave $\lvert +\rangle$ and $\lvert -\rangle$ with $\frac{1}{\sqrt2}$ or these $\frac{1}{\sqrt2}$ are 'a' and 'b' parameters and should be replaced with new values.

Comment: Could you explain what $\lvert 00\rangle$ and other vectors are? What is the physics problem they relate to?

Comment: @Andrei Having an explanation in the post certainly wouldn't hurt, but this is pretty standard quantum information stuff. It relates to any quantum two-level system.

Comment: Write out your last equation for general $a$ and $b$, not just $\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}$.

Comment: I think plugging in $a=1$, $b=0$ will also disprove the statement.

Comment: @JahanClaes should I replace $\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}$ in '+' and '-' or there always should be $\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}$?

Comment: @JahanClaes So I have: 
$a\lvert ++\rangle + b\lvert --\rangle
= a\biggl(\frac{1}{\sqrt2}\lvert 0\rangle + \frac{1}{\sqrt2}\lvert 1\rangle\biggr)^2 + b\biggl(\frac{1}{\sqrt2}\lvert 0\rangle - \frac{1}{\sqrt2}\lvert 1\rangle\biggr)^2 
= a\biggl(\frac{1}{2}\lvert 00\rangle + \lvert 01\rangle +\frac{1}{2}\lvert 11\rangle\biggr) + a\biggl(\frac{1}{2}\lvert 00\rangle - \lvert 01\rangle +\frac{1}{2}\lvert 11\rangle\biggr)$

Comment: @user No, because $|01\rangle$ and $|10\rangle$ are different states. Otherwise, yes. And you should group like terms.

Comment: I don't understand the question. The equality is obviously not satisfied when $a=1$, $b=0$, since $$\left|00\right> \neq \left|++\right>.$$ So, if you are looking for an example of why it can't be true, there's your counterexample. Otherwise, what are you trying to prove?

Comment: @EmilioPisanty The problem is to find $a$ and $b$ that make the equation true. The answer is related to the fact that, in an entangled state, the effect of rotating one qubit can be undone by rotating the other qubit (because only the *difference* in angle matters). For example, you may know that both |up down> - |down up> and |left right> - |right left> are the same state: the singlet state.

Comment: Yeah, that's a valid thing to ask. I'll jot something down when I'm at a desktop. It would help to include that clarification in the post itself.

Comment: Just write down the equation $a[1, 0, 0, 0]+b[0, 0, 0, 1]=norm(a[1, 1, 1, 1]+b[1, -1, -1,  1])$, you will see $a=b$ is the only solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From what I understand, you want to characterize the solution space of those $a,b\in\mathbb C$ such that
\begin{align}
a|00⟩+b|11⟩
& =
a|{++}⟩+b|{--}⟩
\\ & =
\frac{a}{\sqrt 2}\left(|00⟩+|01⟩+|10⟩+|11⟩\right)
\\ & \quad +
\frac{b}{\sqrt 2}\left(|00⟩-|01⟩-|10⟩+|11⟩\right)
\\ & =
\frac{a+b}{\sqrt{2}}\left(|00⟩+|11⟩\right)
+\frac{a-b}{\sqrt{2}}\left(|01⟩+|10⟩\right)
.
\end{align}

As you can see, for this to be true you require $a=b$, and that's the only solution.

---

The broader question you asked,

> The answer is related to the fact that, in an entangled state, the effect of rotating one qubit can be undone by rotating the other qubit (because only the difference in angle matters). For example, you may know that both |up down> - |down up> and |left right> - |right left> are the same state: the singlet state.

is in fact strictly broader. Indeed, if you take a maximally entangled state, then a rotation in one qubit can always be undone by another rotation on the other qubit. However, in the general case there is no requirement that these rotations be identical.

Consider, then, an entangled state of the form $a|00⟩+b|11⟩$, and apply the rotations
\begin{align}
|0⟩&=\cos(\theta) |↑⟩ + e^{i\phi}\sin(\theta) |↓⟩ \\
|1⟩&=- e^{-i\phi}\sin(\theta) |↑⟩ +\cos(\theta) |↓⟩
\end{align}
on the first qubit and
\begin{align}
|0⟩&=\cos(\vartheta) |u⟩ + e^{i\varphi}\sin(\vartheta) |d⟩ \\
|1⟩&=- e^{-i\varphi}\sin(\vartheta) |u⟩ +\cos(\vartheta) |d⟩
\end{align}
on the second one. Then the state transforms to
\begin{align}
a|00⟩+b|11⟩
& =
a\left(
 \cos(\theta)\cos(\vartheta)|↑\!\mathrm u⟩
 +e^{i\phi}\sin(\theta)\cos(\vartheta)|↓\!\mathrm u⟩
\vphantom{e^{-i(\phi+\varphi)}} \right. \\ & \qquad \left.
 +e^{i\varphi}\cos(\theta)\sin(\vartheta)|↑\!\mathrm d⟩
 +e^{i(\phi+\varphi)}\sin(\theta)\sin(\vartheta)|↓\!\mathrm d⟩
\right)
\\ & \quad +
b\left(
 e^{-i(\phi+\varphi)}\sin(\theta)\sin(\vartheta)|↑\!\mathrm u⟩
 -e^{-i\varphi}\cos(\theta)\sin(\vartheta)|↓\!\mathrm u⟩
\right. \\ & \quad \qquad \left. \vphantom{e^{-i(\phi+\varphi)}}
 -e^{-i\phi}\sin(\theta)\cos(\vartheta)|↑\!\mathrm d⟩
 +\cos(\theta)\cos(\vartheta)|↓\!\mathrm d⟩
\right)
\\ & = 
\left(a\cos(\theta)\cos(\vartheta) +b e^{-i(\phi+\varphi)}\sin(\theta)\sin(\vartheta)\right)|↑\!\mathrm u⟩
\\ & \quad +
\left(ae^{i\phi}\sin(\theta)\cos(\vartheta) -b e^{-i\varphi}\cos(\theta)\sin(\vartheta) \right)|↓\!\mathrm u⟩
\\ & \quad +
\left( a e^{i\varphi}\cos(\theta)\sin(\vartheta) - b e^{-i\phi}\sin(\theta)\cos(\vartheta) \right)|↑\!\mathrm d⟩
\\ & \quad +
\left( a e^{i(\phi+\varphi)}\sin(\theta)\sin(\vartheta) + b \cos(\theta)\cos(\vartheta) \right)|↓\!\mathrm d⟩
.
\end{align}
Now here it sort of depends what you want the state to look like, but the spirit is that $\theta$ and $\phi$ are given and we want to see what we can do with a suitable choice of $\vartheta$ and $\varphi$. In particular, it's interesting to see if we can eliminate the components along $|↓\!\mathrm u⟩$ and $|↑\!\mathrm d⟩$, for which we need $\alpha=\cos(\vartheta)$ and $\beta=e^{-i\varphi}\sin(\theta)$ to obey the equations
\begin{align}
a^*e^{-i\phi}\sin(\theta)\alpha -b^* \cos(\theta)\beta
& =0
\\ 
b e^{-i\phi}\sin(\theta)\alpha - a \cos(\theta)\beta
& =0
\end{align}
(where I've conjugated the first equation to make things play nicer). In general, though, this is not possible, because you have two homogeneous linear equations in two variables, and you're looking for a nonzero solution, so this will only work if the system is degenerate, i.e. when its determinant vanishes:
\begin{align}
0 = \det\!\begin{pmatrix}
a^*e^{-i\phi}\sin(\theta) &  -b^* \cos(\theta)\\ 
b e^{-i\phi}\sin(\theta) & - a \cos(\theta)
\end{pmatrix}
= -\left(|a|^2-|b|^2\right)e^{-i\phi}\sin(\theta)\cos(\theta)
.
\end{align}

This gives a necessary and sufficient condition for what we want: the components along  $|↓\!\mathrm u⟩$ and $|↑\!\mathrm d⟩$ can vanish simultaneously if and only if $|a|=|b|$, which is the condition for maximal entanglement in that subspace. When you're in that case, you only need to solve one of the two equations, say
$$
a^*e^{-i\phi}\sin(\theta)\alpha -b^* \cos(\theta)\beta =0,
$$
and the other one will automatically be satisfied (since they're linearly dependent). Putting in the explicit form of the coefficients,
$$
a^*e^{-i\phi}\sin(\theta)\cos(\vartheta) -b^* \cos(\theta)e^{i\varphi}\sin(\vartheta) =0,
$$
we see that this requires $e^{i\varphi}=\frac{a^*}{b^*}e^{-i\phi}$ and equivalently $\varphi = -\phi+\arg(a^*/b^*)$, leaving us with
$$
|a|\sin(\theta)\cos(\vartheta) -|b| \cos(\theta)\sin(\vartheta) =0,
$$
and in turn this requires that $\vartheta=\theta$.

If we then go back to our state, we know it will be in the subspace spanned by $|↑\!\mathrm u⟩$ and $|↓\!\mathrm d⟩$, but we don't yet know the coefficients it will have in that basis, so we need to calculate:
\begin{align}
a|00⟩+b|11⟩
& =
\left(a\cos^2(\theta) +\frac{|b|^2}{a^*}\sin^2(\theta)\right)|↑\!\mathrm u⟩
\\ & \quad +
\left( \frac{|a|^2}{b^*}\sin^2(\theta) + b \cos^2(\theta) \right)|↓\!\mathrm d⟩
\\ & =
a|↑\!\mathrm u⟩+b|↓\!\mathrm d⟩
,
\end{align}
so you do respect the form. However, note again that (i) this requires maximal entanglement, $|a|=|b|$, within the $\operatorname{span}\{|00⟩,|11⟩\}$ subspace, (ii) the rotation on the first qubit completely determines the rotation on the second one, and (iii) the rotations are not identical, because the phase $\varphi$ is generally opposite to $\phi$. This extends the case you're interested in up to the maximally broad case it is valid in.